# Почему njs (nginx js) не работает?

Tags: nginx

### Что есть

- nginx.conf

> ```
> user  nginx root;
> worker_processes  auto;
>
> env VERBOSE_MODE=notice;
>
> pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
> load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;
>
> events {
>     worker_connections  1024;
> }
>
> http {
>     js_include fetch_env.js;
>     js_set $verbose get_verbose_mode;
>     error_log     /var/log/nginx/error.log $verbose;
> }
> ```

- docker image nginx:alpine
- fetch_env.js находиться в рутовой директории nginx

> ```
> function get_verbose_mode(r) {
>     return process.env.VERBOSE_MODE;
> }
> ```

### Проблема

- nginx не запускаеться, ошибка

> [emerg] invalid log level "$verbose" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: njs работает. Просто в error_log нельзя использовать переменные. Вообще.

Comment: @AlexeyTen невериться, потому что в официльном примере https://gist.github.com/nginx-gists/49e2f6f6b0a36ed9846dd63cddbd742a#file-header_logging-conf переменные хорошо работают для access_log

Comment: access_log и error_log это абсолютно разные директивы из разных модулей.